Quick documentation in Android Studio is not fully shown on my laptop
I recently noticed that the quick documentation that pops up when I hover over a function or press Ctrl + Q is not the same on my PC and my laptop.
On my computer, I have a nice documentation that not only shows what the function needs, but it also gives me a short description of what it does and how.
On my laptop, it only gives me the required inputs for the function to work with no more information.
Background:
No extra plugins added on either
On PC: Android Studio Hedgehog
On laptop: Android Studio Iguana
Documentation on PC:

Documentation on Laptop:

This feature is kinda necessary as I don't know what every function does in the library that I am using, and I need a quick and brief way to view the most necessary information on functions
If you have any ideas on what to do so that the full documentation shows up on my laptop please clue me in.
I have searched for a couple of days and have done these troubleshooting steps:

Reinstalling Android Studio on the laptop

Invalidating Caches (including file system, local history, VCS logs and indexes, embedded browser engine cache)


This has resulted in no change.

The shown help text are JavaDoc messages which AFAIK are included in the source code bundles of the Android API. Check the Android SDK manager if you have downloaded the source code bundle for the API your project used

Found a kind of bad solution, I switched my laptop over to hedgehog. Now I have the full documentation though

This could use some more information.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
